# Opening a file using Mac osx application is not receiving the file path as an argument

Tags: macos, shell

I set a file type to open with my own application as default. But whenever I open the file, I am not getting the file path as an argument which I need to process further.

I created a shell script as in the same name of application executable in the path `/Applications/myApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp` and set the necessary arguments which ever received to the executable which I need to call finally with the variable `$@` or `$*`.

But I'm getting something like `psn_0_700587`.

I don't know what should I do to get the exact file path in shell script.

Answer (score 1):

When you double-click on a file to start your application you will not receive the filename as an argument to the `main` function. Rather your application delegate will receive the message `application:openFile:`.
See the documentation of [NSApplicationDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks it helped. I have done that it was a bug in my application creation process.